# Combine several textures into one

Tags: materials, uv, texture-baking

This might have been answered before, but my problem is a little bit more complicated. I'm porting some WW2 warship models and they have lots of different small models like cranes, anchors, lifeboats and whatnot. Each one of those models has its own material, making it absurdly complicated to export them all as textures one by one.

This is the problem I'm currently facing, as you can see on the right there are dozens of individual materials, and my goal is to join them all into a single one if possible so I don't have to export them one by one:

[image]

Comment: I want to add that those materials have both a diffuse and a normal map texture, so I'd like to know if it's possible to combine all the normal maps into one single texture as well

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you want to keep the quality of the textures maybe you need to make 4 or 5 materials, or a very large texture for all. For one material you need to join a couple of meshes, make a "Lightmap Pack" unwrap and then a bake of the textures, that way you'll have a single texture for all the meshes you have joined

Comment: I've already joined all the meshes into one single object, so could I just unwrap the whole object to get all the materials into a single texture? And what about normal maps, each one of those materials has one and I also need to get one single texture of it to convert it to .vtf later.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point. If you export to obj it will export all your materials including the textures. If you were to combine all existing image textures into one single huge image texture, then you'd have to edit all UV-Maps to fit to the new image texture. That would be even more work to do....

Comment: I'm exporting to .smd for the Source engine, and I'll need to convert each texture to .vtf manually. There are approximately 70 materials in there, each one having both a diffuse and a normal map texture, so I would have to manually convert 140 textures. I think editing the UV maps would be at least twice as fast.

Comment: Converting textures can be done with a script, editing the UV maps is hard manual work.

Comment: The problem with those textures is that each one of them is in a separate folder, so unless there's a script that can read the .blend project, fetch each texture and copy them to a single directory for later bulk-conversion using VTFEdit, I don't think it will work.